# Meshes disappear after barbajs transition

Tags: three.js, barbajs

can't reinitialize my threejs scene and meshes when i'm heading back to the home from my inside page. Does any one can see where the problem is ? I've been console logging the meshes, they appear in the console but not on the screen. Why ? Does anyone with more experience on mixing barba and threejs know ?

I've made a codeSandbox for more insight on the code : https://codesandbox.io/p/github/Serotoninene/webglCarousel/draft/pedantic-bohr?file=/src/inside.html:44,48&workspaceId=920cf671-f4e1-42cb-92f2-5c4639d15ed2

here is my barba function

```js
  barba() {
    let that = this;

    barba.init({
      debug: true,
      transitions: [
        {
          name: "from-home-page-transition",
          from: {
            namespace: ["home"],
          },
          beforeLeave(data) {},
          leave(data) {
            // LEAVING HOME
            const tl = gsap.timeline();
            return tl.to(that.settings, {
              progress: 1,
              duration: 0.8,
              ease: Power3.easeInOut,
            });
          },
          afterLeave(data) {
            that.cleanUp();
          },
          beforeEnter(data) {
            const img = data.next.container.querySelector(".image img");
          },
          enter(data) {
            insideAnim();
          },
        },
        {
          name: "from-page-to-home",
          from: {
            namespace: ["inside"],
          },
          leave(data) {
            // LEAVING PROJECT PAGE
            const tl = gsap.timeline();
            return tl.to(data.current.container, {
              x: "-100%",
            });
          },
          async enter(data) {
            that.handleSettings();
            that.addObjects();
          },
        },
      ],
    });
  }
here is my addObjects function :

 async addObjects() {
    const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

    for (let i = 0; i < this.n; i++) {
      const texture = await textureLoader.loadAsync(content[i].image);
      this.material[i] = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        uniforms: {
          uScrollY: { value: 0.0 },
          uProgress: { value: 0.0 },
          uResolution: {
            value: new THREE.Vector2(this.ndcWidth, this.ndcHeight),
          },
          uQuadSize: {
            value: new THREE.Vector2(
              this.settings.meshWidth,
              this.settings.meshHeight
            ),
          },
          uTexture: { value: texture },
          uTextureSize: {
            value: new THREE.Vector2(texture.image.width, texture.image.height),
          },
          uValue: { value: 0 },
        },
        vertexShader: vertexShader,
        fragmentShader: fragmentShader,
      });

      const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1, 32, 32),
        this.material[i]
      );

      if (this.sizes.width < 768) {
        mesh.position.y = 0.2;
      } else {
        mesh.position.y = 0.1;
      }
      mesh.position.x = i * this.margin;

      mesh.scale.set(this.settings.meshWidth, this.settings.meshHeight, 1);
      this.meshes.push(mesh);
      this.scene.add(mesh);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a better understanding of the problem, I made a more simple example using a very basic threejs scene and simple barbajs transitions : https://codesandbox.io/p/github/Serotoninene/webglCarousel/draft/pedantic-bohr?file=/src/script.js:56,44&workspaceId=920cf671-f4e1-42cb-92f2-5c4639d15ed2

Here is what I've found :

- the "leave" function of barbajs must return something but the "enter" must not.
- the cleanup must be thorough, you should remove the scene and dispose the render but also remove all eventsListeners;
- I had to reset the scene, render and reselect the dom element I wanted to use as canvasContainer
- and of course recreate the meshes and reset the requestAnimationFrame :)

I also learned that making the most simplified version is a great way to find the answer !

Hope this will help,
Cheers

ps : if you see ways to improve my code or have more infos on barba/threejs (why do we need to return on leave and not on enter ?) don't hold back !